# Is button.close missing in close.less?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

As you can see on [this screenshot](http://www.mediafire.com/i/?ckpw2kpeaootar5) the close button is not styled properly on my website.

I use bootstrap with less and I could not find the button.close class in my less code (I could find this class in [this bootstrap page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts)).

I suppose it's supposed to be in close.less ?

At least when I add it here it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

button.close is in close.less

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/close.less

make sure you are using

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
```

and not

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
```

for elder version of the twitter bootstrap and iso-8859-1, try with utf-8.

If you still have problems, use jsFiddle to post your code and I will have a look.

Comment: button.close was not in close.less in my Bootstrap version (I am pretty sure I didn't remove it myself) but everything works perfectly now, thanks !